# How to restrict user from selecting dates 5 days from the current date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I am working with a Reservation page and selection of date is required where in user can only select dates on the 5th day on wards from the current date.

Ex: current date is Jan 1, 2016 - the user can only select reservation date from the 6th of January and on wards.

Comment: Are you using jquery datepicker or what?

Comment: <asp:Calendar ID="ArrivalCalendar" runat="server" ondayrender="ArrivalCalendar_DayRender"></asp:Calendar>

Comment: 'protected void ArrivalCalendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)'
        {
            if (e.Day.Date < DateTime.Now && e.Day.Date <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(5))
            {
                e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
                e.Cell.Enabled = false;
            }
        }'

Comment: That is my current code and I can't find a way on my problem